# How to best parse a string in rust

Tags: string, parsing, rust

I'm looking to build a toy string parser in Rust, but fairly beginner to the language. The design I'm thinking of is building a Parser struct, that uses the Iterator trait to grab the next token for the end-user. Something like:

```
pub struct Scanner {
    pub start: i32, // start of token
    pub current: i32, //current char
    pub line: i32, //line currently being parsed
    pub char_it: //storing some kind of string iterator state
}

...

impl Iterator for Scanner {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Token> {
        do_something(self.char_it.next()); // look at the next char or combination of chars and build a token
        return some_token;
}
```

1. Is this the most idiomatic way to approach this design? In most languages I would just track an index or pointer over the string I'm parsing but my understanding is it's not best practice to index into a string, and usually you want to use an Iterator like `test_str.chars().next()`.
2. How exactly would you store an iterator in a struct so that it keeps an internal state of where the scanner is at? What datatype is this? I tried `pub char_it: Iterator<Item = char>` which did not seem to work.
3. Is there any way to index into the data structure without an iterator efficiently? I know there's `char_at()`, but I hear this is potentially an O(n) operation?

Thanks

Comment: You need to write a book to suggest ways to iterate over a string or store an iterator in a struct?

Comment: Since this question is rather open-ended, you might want to consider asking somewhere other than Stack Overflow, such as the Rust User Forum at users.rust-lang.org or on the official Discord server. Questions like this *can* be good on SO, but IMO it's a difficult balance to strike between too vague ("how is code formed?"), opinion-based ("which of these equally valid designs is the best") and low-effort ("here are all my requirements, please provide the solution"). To improve this question, I would start by splitting off the easy smaller questions like "Is `char_at` O(n)?"

Comment: Although the answer to that one depends on what semantics you want -- `char_at` is not a standard Rust function, so I assume you're thinking either of `s.chars().nth(n)` (which is O(n)) or `s[n..].chars().next()` (which is O(1), but panics if `n` is not a UTF-8 character boundary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the most idiomatic way to approach this design? In most languages I would just track an index or pointer over the string I'm parsing but my understanding is it's not best practice to index into a string, and usually you want to use an Iterator like `test_str.chars().next()`.

Using either indexes or an iterator would be fine. The issue to keep in mind is that Rust strings are utf-8 encoded and directly indexing into the middle of a multi-byte code point will result in a panic. However, if you're determining the index via [`.char_indices()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html?search=#method.char_indices) or another utf-8 aware mechanism, then it won't be a problem.

---

> How exactly would you store an iterator in a struct so that it keeps an internal state of where the scanner is at? What datatype is this? I tried `pub char_it: Iterator<Item = char>` which did not seem to work.

There are a few ways to go about:

1. In this case you can use the type directly. [`.chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) always returns a [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) value and can be used directly (and adding the lifetime binding the iterator to the original string):

   ```
   use std::str::Chars;

   pub struct Scanner<'source> {
       pub start: i32,
       pub current: i32,
       pub line: i32,
       pub char_it: Chars<'source>
   }
   ```
2. `Iterator` is a trait, not a concrete type itself. But in general, you can make a type generic over the iterator type:

   ```
   pub struct Scanner<I: Iterator<Item = char>> {
       pub start: i32,
       pub current: i32,
       pub line: i32,
       pub char_it: I
   }
   ```
3. The other option is to use a trait object (using `Box`):

   ```
   pub struct Scanner<'source> {
       pub start: i32,
       pub current: i32,
       pub line: i32,
       pub char_it: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = char> + 'source>
   }
   ```

   The `'source` lifetime is needed here because trait objects are `'static` by default, which [won't work for owned strings](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c245dd48eb928106eab6a958abf1230).
4. For a purpose like this, I would recommend keeping the slice of the string that is left to be parsed:

   ```
   pub struct Scanner<'source> {
       pub start: i32,
       pub current: i32,
       pub line: i32,
       pub char_it: &'source str
   }
   ```

   You can use `.chars()` on the slice and store it back with [`.as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.as_str) to get the remaining slice.

---

> Is there any way to index into the data structure without an iterator efficiently? I know there's `char_at()`, but I hear this is potentially an O(n) operation?

I don't know what `char_at()` is. Using `[]` to index a string is O(1) because it just works on bytes. But again, it will panic if its within a code point.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're parsing, and whether you need to move backwards through a stream, or peek from a stream.  Probably you will want to make some kind of object to represent the input stream, complete with a reference to the stream data, as well as the current positions in that data.  That input stream object would then have the low level methods needed to read in the next expected input, whether it is a single character or a whole token.  It's hard to elaborate more than that without knowing more specifics.  You might want to look at some of the existing parsing libraries, such as https://github.com/Geal/nom